# Too much empty space before a TikZ CD with a bent arrow with looseness

Tags: spacing, tikz-cd, vertical-spacing

As you can see in the following example, there is too much empty space between the text and the diagram when I use an arrow with `bend left=100, looseness=2`.

How can I avoid it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\blindtext As you can see, there is too much empty space here:
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
D\ar[r]\ar[dr, bend left=100, 
    looseness=2]&U\ar[dl]\\
C\ar[r] & K
\end{tikzcd}    
\]
\blindtext
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
D\ar[r]&U\ar[dl]\\
C\ar[r] & K
\end{tikzcd}    
\]
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The control points that Ti*k*Z considers part of the bounding box are too far outside. I think there was some code for tight bounding boxes somewhere.

Comment: @Skillmon Maybe `\useasboundingbox`...

Comment: You could use `\useasboundingbox` (I have no idea how in `tikz-cd` as I don't use it), that would be a manual approach to fix this.

Comment: See https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-bbox?lang=en. It may help you.

Comment: @CarLaTeX, done.

Comment: @CarLaTeX you're right. It would be nice if Zarko could add this answer to the other question --- that would be easier for people searching for similar problems

Comment: @Rmano, which questions do you mean? The one to which this question is duplicate?  It is already answered by marmot (using one of his alias names), so I’m not sure if it’s wise to add there another answer based on his code. I need to rethinking about how to wording the answer, if I will do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once upon a time **@marmot** also know as **@Schrödinger's cat** wrote the interesting Ti*k*Z library `bbox` which solves most problems similar to yours. The library is no longer part of the Ti*k*Z bundle (consult [marmotghost](https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-bbox)), but it is available on [CTAN](http://%20ctan.org/pkg/tikz-bbox?lang=en.)  nonetheless.

Loading it you can write:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{bbox}

\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}

\blindtext 
As you can see, there is too much empty space here:
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[bezier bounding box]
D\ar[r]\ar[dr, bend left=100,
    looseness=2]&U\ar[dl]\\
C\ar[r] & K
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

and obtain the following result:

[image]

Comment: @egreg, than you very much for correcting my terrible English.